# I need the currect math equation for updating a score

Tags: javascript, math, javascript-objects, equation

notice that there are 3 differnt amountChosen 10,50 and 100 and the are 3 differnt leverage chosen 1,2 and 3   ok only one amount chosen and one leverage chosen can be true.
next is the current score which at defualt is 10, ok now i want the amount chosen to be devided by the current score and the result of that I want to be times by the leverage chosen. for example amountchosen10 / currentscore10 which should = 1 * leveragechosen2 which should = 2 + currentscore should = 12.  But for some reason i'm not getting the exact results I want?

function tradeResult(){

// the if statement conditions below 800 > 200 is just simple logic for testing purposes will change it once i get the equation further down to work right.

```
    if(800 > 200){
         
    
      if(amountRecord.innerText === amountButtonOne.innerText){
        amountChosen = 10;
      }
      else if(amountRecord.innerText === amountButtonTwo.innerText){
        amountChosen = 50;
      }
      else if(amountRecord.innerText === amountButtonThree.innerText){
        amountChosen = 100;
      }
    
      
    
      if(leverageRecord.innerText === leverageButtonOne.innerText){
        leverageChosen = 1;
      }
      else if(leverageRecord.innerText === leverageButtonTwo.innerText){
        leverageChosen = 2;
      }
      else if(leverageRecord.innerText === leverageButtonThree.innerText){
        leverageChosen = 3;
      }
      
    
    let yourProfit = currentScore / amountChosen * leverageChosen;
    score.innerHTML = currentScore + yourProfit;
   
    




    }else if(600 < 800){
      
     
      
   
    
      if(amountRecord.innerText === amountButtonOne.innerText){
        amountChosen = 10;
      }
      else if(amountRecord.innerText === amountButtonTwo.innerText){
        amountChosen = 50;
      }
      else if(amountRecord.innerText === amountButtonThree.innerText){
        amountChosen = 100;
      }
      
    
    
      if(leverageRecord.innerText === leverageButtonOne.innerText){
        leverageChosen = 1;
      }
      else if(leverageRecord.innerText === leverageButtonTwo.innerText){
        leverageChosen = 2;
      }
      else if(leverageRecord.innerText === leverageButtonThree.innerText){
        leverageChosen = 3;
      }
      
    
    let yourProfit = currentScore / amountChosen * leverageChosen;
    score.innerHTML = currentScore + yourProfit;
    
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add more information about exactly where you are having a problem

Comment: `let newScore = currentScore + amountChosen / currentScore  * leverageChosen;` ? What are the values of those variables prior to the calculation?